# Return function not working- new_node value is printing inside but while returning it is not returning it

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, rightscale

```
def function():
    res = get_nodes(api_server_call, token)
    newnode = ""
    #endTime = ""
    for node in res:
        if (node['state'] == "booting" or node['state'] == "queued"):
            newnode = node['name']
            print("new node is : " + newnode)
            return newnode
    if(newnode == ""):
        function()


new_node = function() >this is main function from where above function is called
print(new_node)
```

> above function return me newnode that is booting or queued I am getting it on printing but while returning it is returning None

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data  that produces your problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: add an extra 'return new_node' at the last line of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning None is the default behaviour when you do not put a return statement at the end of your function. If the function has several ways to end, you have to end each coding path by a return, or put one at the end of it. If your newnode is not empty, you do nothing, so default value None is returned. To be sure, it is safer to put a valid return statement at the end of each code path:

So you forgot extra 'return newnode' at the last line of the function:

```
def function():
    res = get_nodes(api_server_call, token)
    newnode = ""
    #endTime = ""
    for node in res:
        if (node['state'] == "booting" or node['state'] == "queued"):
            newnode = node['name']
            print("new node is : " + newnode)
            return newnode

    if(newnode == ""):
        return function()

    return newnode


## main part of the code:
new_node = function() ##>this is main where function is called
print(new_node)
```

Comment: Please check my updated code now as last two lines from where function is being called, please recheck again and confirm

Comment: Same problem, the last line of your function needs a 'return' statement. Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: do you handle the cass where no new node is available ? Please add sample data so we can try and debug further with you.

Comment: that is not in function , last two lines are from where function is being called

Comment: I know, and it is taken into account as the indentation shows. Have you tried this ? and do you have more errors ? If I have a bad reading, please update indentation to show it.

Comment: Each time you do not find a newnode, you call function() again. Is it intended ?

Comment: Yes it is intended , last two lines basically to call that function like main .

Comment: @RaviTomar: so have you tried this answer ? have you more errors or bugs ? please -tell us more ...

Comment: i got it wee need to store new node value if(newnode == ""): here newnode = newnode

Comment: @RaviTomar : if it is good for you, please accept the answer.